# Как вывести четные числа?c#

Tags: c#

Всем доброго вечера . Давненько решил столь простую задачку за один раз , спустя долгое время вернулся вновь в изучение c# и вот при повторении материала застопорился на вот такой простой задачке.
Пробовал по разному вывести только лишь четные числа ,но что то не додуматься.

Поможет кто может ?)
Вот мой код :

```
        int num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        int res = 1;
       
        while(res<=num)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(res);
            res++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Добавьте условие чётности. Перед выводом и все.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно использовать оператор `%`, который возвращает остаток от деления левого на правое. То есть, например, если напишем `10 % 2`, то вернет `0`. Так и можно определять четность числа.

```
Console.WriteLine("Введите длину: ");
int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    if (i % 2 == 0)
        Console.WriteLine(i);
```

P.S. Если заранее известно, сколько будет выводов, сколько раз должна повторится итерация, то лучше использовать цикл со счетчиком `for`. И с его помощью можно по другому решить данную задачу.

```
Console.WriteLine("Введите длину: ");
int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    
for (int i = 2; i <= n; i += 2)
    Console.WriteLine(i);
```

Comment: страйтесь в своих ответах форматировать код с нормальными отступами, чтобы сдвинуть код в Visual Studio к левому краю, выделите нужный фрагмент и нажмите нужное количество раз `Shift+Tab`, а потом после копирования, чтобы в студии вернуть форматирование на место, жмите либо `Tab`, либо `Ctrl+Z`.

Comment: Извиняюсь, просто скопировал не все :D А так отступы в VS нормальные)

Comment: Сейчас покажу, как можно...Смотрите.

Comment: Спасибо :D Я не мастер редактирования текста xD

Comment: Если вы решили делать качественные посты, учитесь их оформлять красиво - [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) и [еще ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/editing-help). К тому же, качественно оформленные ответы более охотно плюсуют.

Comment: Та не, просто решил зайти посмотреть, а тут как раз попались простетские задачи) Так что не знаю, когда следующий раз что-то сделаю) Но все равно спасибо

Answer (score 0):

```
class Program 
{
    static void Main(string[] args)  
    {
       int num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
       int res = 1;
       while (res < num)
       {
        Console.WriteLine(res+1);
        res+= 2;
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

```
    {
        int num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        int res = 1;
       
        if (res == 1)

        {
         res += 1;
        }

        while (res <= num)

        {
            Console.WriteLine(res);
            res += 2;
        }

    }
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Воздержитесь он вандальных действий в других ответах, лучше доработайте свой собственный.